# Evaluate $\int_0^1 t^m(1+t)^n dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_0^1 t^m(1+t)^n dt$$

My try:

Let $$I(m,n)= \int_0^1 t^m(1+t)^n dt=\int_0^1 t^{m-1} (1+t-1)(1+t)^n dt=I(m-1,n+1)- I(m-1,n)$$

And by using Integration by parts we get $$I(m,n)=\frac {2^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac {m}{n+1} I(m-1,n+1)$$

From these two equations we get $$I(m,n)=\frac {2^{n+1}}{m+n+1} - \frac {m}{m+n+1} I(m-1,n)$$

Now I was only asked to find the recurrence but I am wondering if there could be any closed form solution to it. So in the process of finding the closed form I found out that  $$I(m,n)=\frac {2^{n+1}}{m+n+1} - \frac {m\cdot 2^{n+1}}{(m+n+1)(m+n)}+\frac {m(m-1)\cdot 2^{n+1}}{(m+n+1)(m+n)(m+n-1)}-\cdots\cdots +\frac {(-1)^{m-1}m!\cdot 2^{n+1}}{(m+n+1)(m+n)(m+n-1)\cdots (n+2)}+\frac {(-1)^{m}m!\cdot 2^{n+1}}{(m+n+1)(m+n)(m+n-1)\cdots (n+2)(n+1)}+ \frac {(-1)^m \cdot m!}{ (m+n+1)(m+n)(m+n-1)\cdots (n+1)}$$

The series seems to follow some pattern But I am not able to simplify this summation. I tried writing the general term but couldn't find a proper one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Spencer Your formula seems to be wrong. Try $n=0$. And one more thing,  there is no more information about m, n provided in the question

Comment: @Spencer $$I(m,0)=\int_0^1 t^m dt = \frac {1}{m+1} $$  But your formula yields $I(m,0)=\frac {m+2}{m+1}$

Comment: @J.G. Yep.......

Comment: @user90369 Oh I absolutely forgot about binomial. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\,m>-1\,$ use $\,\displaystyle (1+t)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty {\binom n k}t^k\,$ .

Comment: @J.G. and Manthanein Wow, I really wasn't focusing on that formula at all. Sorry about that.

Comment: For integer $m$, $I(m,n)=(-1)^{m+1} B(-1,m+1,n+1)$. Without that restriction, $I(m,n)={_2F_1}(m+1,-n;m+2;-1)/(m+1)$.

Comment: @Maxim That's a nice hypergeometric result. You should write an answer that proves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options, none of them especially neat. (I also recommend you to double-check these calculations.) You can use the substitution $u=\dfrac{t}{1+t^2}$ to write the integral as an [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). It's easiest to do this by writing $t=\tan^2 x,\,u=\sin^2 x$, viz.$$I(m,\,n)=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin^{2m+1}x\cos^{-2m-2n-3}x dx=\operatorname{B}(\frac{1}{2};\,m+1,\,-m-n-1).$$

For $n$ a non-negative integer you can use$$I(m,\,n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{m+k+1}.$$For $m$ a non-negative integer, you can define $f_n(a):=\int_0^1 (1+at)^n\text{d}t=\dfrac{(1+a)^{n+1}-1}{a(n+1)}$ so $I(m,\,n)=\dfrac{f_{m+n}^{(m)}(1)}{\prod_{i=1}^m (n+i)}$.

Comment: I think you meant "For $n$ a nonnegative integer" (not $m$), but the sum $$I(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{m+k+1}\,\binom{n}{k}$$ should hold for all $n$.

Comment: I have already tried writing it in terms of incomplete beta function but it didn't seem to be much promising and leads to nowhere.  I wonder how you got the second closed form.  The last one actually is bit more of a very tedious task to write $n^{th}$ derivative of the function